# How to get url parameter in knockout js in checkout/index/index/#payment page

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, html

I am trying to replace my custom payment method's button called "submit request" to "place order" button when the status is approved.
I send status in URL parameter and now want to get it in knockout and data-bind in .html file and add CSS that if status is approved than "submit request" button is display:none and "place order" button is display:block.
If status is not approved than "submit request" button is display:block and "place order" button is display:none.
my URL is `/checkout/index/index/status/approved/#payment`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you can achieve this in your payment method renderer js.There should be a js file (assume the file name is whatever.js) under YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/whatever.js.
You can work on that file to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Add code of your method renderer js as well as ko html template.